# Can Visual Studio 2005 Pro generate UML style class diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio, uml

Can Visual Studio 2005 Pro generate UML style class diagrams?

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the magnifier icon in Solution Explorer window. Then the diagram will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

2005 does not have a UML modeler. The class designer mentioned above will allow you to model and code gen your classes but it is not a UML tool per-say. If you're not concerned with code gen from the model then I would suggest to just use Viso. If you do want to generate code from a true UML model then you may want to consider something like  [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).

[2010 Team System](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/a-firist-look-visual-studio-20) how-ever is supposed to have full UML modeling and code generate built in. Only one more year to wait :-P

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288743.aspx)

Some details from that page:

> ## **Visual Studio 2005 Class Designer**
>
> ## <sub>Visual Studio .NET 2003</sub>
>
> - Applies to: Visual Studio® 2005
>
> **Summary:**
>   The Visual Studio Class Designer lets you visualize the structure of classes and their relationships, create new classes using a visual design environment, and easily refactor classes. This whitepaper walks you through some of these tasks. (7 printed pages)
>
> **Introduction**
>   The Visual Studio Class Designer is a fully-functional, visual design environment for the Common Language Runtime. The Visual Studio Class Designer lets you visualize the structure of classes and other types, and through these visual representations edit their source code. Changes made to the class diagram are immediately reflected in code, and changes made to the code immediately affect the appearance of the designer. This synchronous relationship between designer and code makes it easy to create and configure complex CLR types visually.
>
> The Class Designer contains features specifically designed to help you refactor your code as well as allow you to easily rename identifiers and override methods. You can automatically generate classes and structures, and implement interfaces by automatically generating stubs.
>
> Finally, Class Designer also serves as a communication tool by letting you easily communicate areas of your code base to colleagues. Class diagrams can be printed to hard copy or saved as images for display in HTML pages or PowerPoint presentations.
>
> > **Note:**
> >     This document was developed prior to the product's release to manufacturing, and as such, you may find inconsistencies with the details included here and those found in the shipping product. The information is based on the product at the time this document was created and should be used for planning purposes only. Information is subject to change at any time without prior notice...

Comment: @flodin - probably downvoted because the answer was only a link. Some detail form the linked page should have been included in the answer. If the page at the URL goes missing (changed URL, ...), there's no way to use some text from that page to search for it, and no way to tell what that page said. The linked page is a great resource and rather than downvote I'd edit it and add some detail. I'll do that now. =)